# Using set-builder notation to express a function

Tags: set-theory, set-partition

I would like to use set builder notation for the following text:

The functions maps a series of numbers (L) (assume all positive) to a list of sub-partitions (P). Each sub-partition contains some elements of the L. The union of all sub-partitions is L and there is no common element between two sub-partitions. Also each sub-partition has at least one element.

$f: L  \rightarrow P$

$P=\{p: |p_i| \geq 1,   \cup p_i=U,  \cap p_i= \phi\}$

$p_i=[L_{ab}], 1 \leq a,b  \leq m$ (where $m$ is the number of elements in L)

For example, if $L=\{2,4,5,10\}$, then $p_1=[2,4,5]$ (or $L_{13}$). Therefore $P=\{(2,4,5),(10)\}$. I would like to know if the notations are correct in the set-builder rules and reader understands that. If you think another representation is more meaningful, please let me know.

Comment: If $P= \{ p_i \}$ is the partition, the conditions amount to: (i) $p_i \ne \emptyset$ for every $i$ (partitions are not empty), (ii) $p_i \cap p_j= \emptyset, i \ne j$ (disjointness) and (iii) $\cup p_i=L$ (the "universe" is $L$).

Comment: `\varnothing` is used for the empty set instead of `\phi`. Also, this might just be my personal preference, but `\land` is the logical symbol for "and", here replaced by the commas in $\vert p_i\vert\ge 1,\cup p_i=U, \cap p_i=\phi$.